# C# display pdf document in iframe in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

how can i display pdf document in iframe in c# web page:i have a drowpdownlist linked with pdf files,what i need is when i select one item from this list ,iframe will populated with the corresponding pdf document

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [How to Display PDF documents with ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx)

The article describes using a custom server control to do exactly what you're looking for.